# Discord.js - Embedding

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**How can i implement a user mention into this embed?**

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!poke'){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('You got poked!')
            .setColor(0xfcbacb)
            .setDescription(':point_right::point_left: ')
            .setImage('https://tenor.com/view/milk-and-mocha-bear-couple-poke-mad-pissed-gif-12498610')
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is not that clear. Kindly explain more the problem and show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

So, I think you want to mention the user outside the embed, so I will explain how to do this
`
You can use the code below to mention the user (If I was incorrect about your question, comment below please):

**Mention the mentioned user:**

```js
message.channel.send(`<@${userToMention.id}>`, embed);
```

**Mention the command author:**

```js
message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>`, embed);
```

Comment: i wanted to do the command, then ping a member ,so the bot will send an embed with a gif + a mention. except its not working

Comment: The link `https://tenor.com/view/milk-and-mocha-bear-couple-poke-mad-pissed-gif-12498610` will not work because the link needs to have **.gif** in their final. 

Try this: `https://media1.tenor.com/images/efce56eba8ffb9e07a7afc0751ad58ed/tenor.gif` (Is the same gif)

Comment: what I mean is that the bot is not responding at all.

Comment: from what i've seen there aren't any errors, it's not responding, it doesn't crash or anything.

Comment: If yes try changing the `.setImage` URL to `https://media1.tenor.com/images/efce56eba8ffb9e07a7afc0751ad58ed/tenor.gif`

Comment: Ok, its working, thanks! one more question, let's say i want to run the command along with a mention and the bot should send the embed + the member mentioned. how can i do that?
and thank you for the support anyway!

Comment: First of all, define the mention function, you can use `let user = message.mentions.users.first()` after, you can use it to send the embed + the mention: __message.channel.send(`<@${user.id}>`, embed);__